# Hibernate ObjectNotFoundException, but object exists

Tags: hibernate, session, grails, transactions

**EDIT:** The error was right, pay me no mind.

---

**TL;DR:  When I try to create a link between two instances in a service, Hibernate complains that one of them isn't found, even though it definitely exists. This appears to have started happening after upgrading to Grails 2.3.8.**

So, my application is a `Call` tracking application.  It has `Users`, and in order to know whether a User is available, we have a class called `ResourceAvailability`:

```
class ResourceAvailability {

    def grailsApplication

    Call            callInstance
    User            resource
    ResourceStatus  resourceStatus
    Date            dateCreated

// ... constraints, etc ...

}
```

(There is no link back from User to ResourceAvailability.)

When a User logs in, accepts a call, or otherwise changes status, his previous availability status is deleted from the table and a new status is created.  That way we can track how long someone has, e.g., been ready while calls are waiting, or how long it's been since they accepted a call.

Without a bunch of error handling code, here's the meat of the `Call` controller's `accept` action:

```
def accept(Long id, Long version) {

    // All the Call stuff works fine...
    def callInstance = Call.get(id)
    callInstance.accept()
    callInstance.save()
    def user = springSecurityService.currentUser

    // Clear out the user's existing Ready or Busy status
    // TODO: Factor out into a service method
    ResourceAvailability.where {
        resource == user && (resourceStatus.statusDescription == "Ready" || resourceStatus.statusDescription == "Busy")
    }?.each { it.delete() }


    // Set new status. The error occurs in this method.
    resourceAvailabilityService.setResourceStatus(user.id, 'Accepted', callInstance)

    // redirect to view

}
```

And the `setResourceStatus` method:

```
void setResourceStatus(Long userId, String resourceStatusDescription, Call callInstance = null) {
    def resource = User.read(userId)

    ResourceStatus resourceStatus = ResourceStatus.findByStatusDescription(resourceStatusDescription)

    /** HERE'S THE PROBLEM LINE **/
    ResourceAvailability resourceAvailabilityInstance = new ResourceAvailability (
        callInstance: callInstance,
        resource: resource,
        resourceStatus: resourceStatus
    ).save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

    new ResourceHistory(resourceAvailabilityInstance).save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

}
```

The exception occurs when trying to save the new `ResourceAvailability`.  (If I remove `flush: true`, it occurs at the end of the method when the transaction commits.)

For reference, here is the exception:

```
ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - ObjectNotFoundException occurred when processing request: [GET] /CallLog/call/accept/17779
No row with the given identifier exists: [com.foobar.calls.User#0]. Stacktrace follows:
```

This appears to have occurred when I upgraded from Grails 2.2.0 to 2.3.8.  I still have the 2.2.0 version and the same code works there.

The `User` (aka resource) that I'm referencing **definitely** exists. This is not occurring during a unit test; I'm running the app and logging in.  It's just when calling this method that Hibernate seems to lose track of the User.

I've machined the code, and the User instance exists inside of the service, both before AND after the `new ResourceAvailability` line.

**EDIT**
So I ran the method again with SQL logging on, and noticed this:

```
2014-05-29 16:10:23,806 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG hibernate.SQL  - insert into resource_availability (version, call_instance_id, date_created, resource_id, resource_status_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2014-05-29 16:10:23,807 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - 0
2014-05-29 16:10:23,807 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - 17779
2014-05-29 16:10:23,808 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [3] as [TIMESTAMP] - Thu May 29 16:10:23 CDT 2014
2014-05-29 16:10:23,808 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [4] as [BIGINT] - 30
2014-05-29 16:10:23,808 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [5] as [BIGINT] - 1
2014-05-29 16:10:23,826 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG hibernate.SQL  - select user0_.id as id24_0_, user0_.version as version24_0_, user0_.account_expired as account3_24_0_, user0_.account_locked as account4_24_0_, user0_.enabled as enabled24_0_, user0_.first_name as first6_24_0_, user0_.last_name as last7_24_0_, user0_.`password` as password8_24_0_, user0_.password_expired as password9_24_0_, user0_.resource_level_id as resource10_24_0_, user0_.username as username24_0_ from user user0_ where user0_.id=?
2014-05-29 16:10:23,826 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - 0
```

Why does it do the `select` after the insert, and why is it using `user.id` of 0???

**EDIT** Upgraded my Grails Hibernate plugin to 3.6.10.15. Didn't fix the issue :/

Comment: Why do you pass in the `id` of `User` and then again `read` it where you already have the user instance from `springSecurityService.currentUser`?

Comment: @dmahapatro I thought maybe that instance was getting closed or otherwise lost at the end of the service transaction, so I tried changing it to this and haven't changed it back yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure enough: I had added a `callCompletedUser` field but not populated it, and in 2.3.8 its default value is 0 instead of null. So, Hibernate was complaining about not being able to find a User with id 0.